# Let $G$ be the group of all the maps from closed interval $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

Let $G$ be the group of all the maps from closed interval $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup $H= \left \{ f  \in G :f(0)=0 \right \}$

Then

$1)$ $H$ is  countable

$2)$ $H$ is uncountable

$3)$ $H$  has countable index

$4)$ $H$ has uncountable index

**Solution I tried**- In this question he is asking about maps not for functions. The number of maps form $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ must be more than $\aleph_0^\mathfrak{c}$. Now I am confused here, how to proceed further because, I have no idea what is $\mathfrak{c}$ times  $\aleph_0$. please give me a hint so that I can solve this further.

Thank you.

Comment: $\mathfrak c$ "times" $\aleph_0$ is $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: so the cardinality of $G$ is $c$ but about $H$ can you please help?

Comment: What is your definition of "map"? If it doesn't mean "function" this needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\varphi\colon G\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\varphi(f)=f(0)$.

Then this map is a group homomorphism (verify it), it is surjective (just consider constant functions) and $H=\ker\varphi$.

Therefore by the homomorphism theorem, $G/H=G/\ker\varphi\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

This answers the question about the index, doesn't it?

Also, since you have just fixed the image at $0$, you can easily seen that $H$ is isomorphic to the group of all function $(0,1]\to\mathbb{Z}$, which has cardinality $\aleph_0^{\mathfrak{c}}=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the set of all the binary sequences (i.e. functions with domain $\mathbb{N}$ and range in $\{ 0, 1 \}$) is uncountable, it can be shown that $H$ is also uncountable.